# how do you create a popdown menu like the one in fuzzyfinder?

Tags: vim

When you launch FuzzyFinder, a 1 row window appears at the top along with a drop down list of matches, which you can go up and down with C-P and C-N. I know how to generate the 1-row mini-window, but how does one generate the drop down list with VimScript?

It looks like this type of drop down list is also used for code completions in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big and complex set of interrelated functionality in Vim, coming under umbrella of 'completion methods'.  I think FuzzyFinder uses mostly "completion functions".  In any case you can start reading about it in Vim help by doing:

```
:h complete-functions
```

and/or

```
:h popupmenu-completion
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert custom functions into the completion drop down, and display it with a right click????? THat'd be interesting (for example, the right click "drop down" would contain yank, put, etc).